# Static information on SharePoint Online page for different views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have quick links to different views of the same SP List. I need to place the same information (instructions etc.) at the top of all the pages showing different views. How do I place the static information ONCE and have users accessing different views see the same static information up top? I am trying to avoid creating different pages.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For modern view pages, you cannot add static information on the top of the page.

As a workaround, I suggest you create a new page, add a text web part to place the static information, the add a quick links web part to store link of different views.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't using quick links mean leaving the original page, and therefore the page with static info? I need to stay on the same page. I know there are the drop down view selections, I was hoping to use buttons or something more "hip" to navigate to different views